# Error When Importing DB objects from Datawarehouse to Database Project

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I am trying to import my Datawarehouse objects to the database project.
But in the middle of the process I get the below issue and none imported to the project. Any idea why this issue happens? Everyone who use might not have the login manager role permission.

Error message:
25/07/2023 2:55:27 PM   Your permissions to see all objects in the server or database could not be verified.  The original error was:
The SELECT permission has not been granted on 'sys.sql_logins' for the 'master' database. You must be a member of the 'loginmanager' role to access this system view.
Reverse Engineer will continue the import process, and logins will not be imported.
The reverse engineering operation will attempt to continue anyway, but the resulting model might be incomplete, malformed, or incorrect.
25/07/2023 2:55:27 PM   An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlExternalDataSource: Unsupported external data source type '6'.
25/07/2023 2:55:27 PM   Your permissions to see all objects in the server or database could not be verified.  The original error was:
The SELECT permission has not been granted on 'sys.sql_logins' for the 'master' database. You must be a member of the 'loginmanager' role to access this system view.
Reverse Engineer will continue the import process, and logins will not be imported.
The reverse engineering operation will attempt to continue anyway, but the resulting model might be incomplete, malformed, or incorrect.
25/07/2023 2:55:27 PM   Finished importing database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it is clear you dont have access on master database to query sys.sql_logins.

The reason for that is based on reverse eng, the import even takes the login details and SQL Logins are created at master db level
[image]